# How to sum column values for each row in two csv files using bash script?

Tags: shell-script, csv

I have two CSV files and i have the requirement to calculate the sum of the 8th column from File1 and File2 for every row. The two CSV files have exactly 24 rows each and to simplify the things i have extracted the 8th row of each CSV file using:

```
awk -F, '{ print $8 }' >> FILE1
awk -F, '{ print $8 }' >> FILE2
```

Now, i have 2 file data in the following format:

**File1**

```
1
2
3
4
```

**File2**

```
2
3
4
5
```

How can i make the calculations in the way that

```
File1.Col1 + File2.Col1 = File3.Col1
File1.Col2 + File2.Col2 = File3.Col2
File1.Col3 + File2.Col3 = File3.Col3
.
.
.
```

resulting in:

**File3**

```
3
5
7
9
```

and so on using Bash Shell script because rest of my processing is being done in the same.

Comment: Don't you mean `File1.Row1 + File2.Row1 = File3.Row1`, etc?

Comment: I suggest doing all of your processing in an `awk` script; there's no need to extract the 8th columns of your CSV files into temporary files. To read two or more files in parallel you can use awk's `getline` statement.

Comment: Ankit: If the below answer has solved your issue please accept it & let the post be solved. It'll help others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paste File1 File2 | awk '{ print $1 + $2; }' > File3`

Comment: Why do we need this ; in print statement?

Comment: Not required for a one liner, I had put some sanity check after that, forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

for avoiding an intermediate file, use:

```
paste <( awk -F, '{ print $8 }' original_file1 ) <( awk -F, '{ print $8 }' original_file2 ) | awk '{print $1+$2}' > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

if both field are in 8th column among 24

```
 paste originalfile1 originalfile2 | awk '{print $8+$32 ; }' > file3
```

Comment: It's 24 rows as per the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [`numsum`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/) and `paste`:

```
paste -d ' ' File[12] | numsum -r > File3
```

Or if *DataFile1* and *DataFile2* are the multi-column files from which *File1* and *File2* were extracted:

```
paste -d ' ' <(cut -f 8 DataFile1) <(cut -f 8 DataFile2) | numsum -r > File3
```